# Do you have to prepend classname to variable in another class?

Tags: java

In the following code, is there a way for test1 to refer to the test2variable without prepending the classname?
I don't know if an import statement would work or if test1 has to extend test2 to avoid having to do that.

```
public class test1  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("its " + test2variable);       // this doesnt work
        System.out.println("its " + test2.test2variable); // this works
    }
}

class test2 {
    public static int test2variable = 2; 
}
```

EDIT:  In this case, the above code is in the same file, so I got an error on the static import statement

Comment: are these classes in the same file or different files?  Also, your class names should be uppercase.

Comment: Actually they are in the same file in this scenario, so I got an error with the the static import statement....

Comment: Make test2 a static class.

Comment: Well, when I add static to the class, I get an error: "Illegal modifier for the class test2; only public, abstract & final are permitted"

Comment: public static class test2, or (more appropriately) public static class Test2.

Comment: But I'm trying to see if this will work in the same file.  Eclipse won't allow me to add the static modifier as mentioned above, and if I just say "public class test2" I get "The public type test2 must be defined in its own file"

Comment: That is in the same file, but not in the same class.

Comment: Please never start your class names with a lowercase letter. It is a long established tradition to start class names with an uppercase letter. If you don't follow this rule, your code will be difficult to read for other people.

Comment: Well FWIW I finally solved this...it's worth noting that the static import will not work unless there is a package declaration (wont work within the default package)

Answer (score 7):

You could use what is called a "static import".

That is, in class `test1`:

```
import static test2.test2variable;
```

This only works because `test2.test2variable` is `static` (and `public`).

---

Also, note that we usually name class with a starting uppercase letter.

Answer (score 3):

Add `import static test2.test2variable;` to your import statements.

Answer (score 0):

`test2variable` only exists in the `test2` class - so you'll need to type the whole thing.

Comment: Except it is a `static` variable, so you can use a static import.